# Using IFrames with Meteor

Tags: iframe, meteor

I've fruitlessly looked for examples of using Meteor with an Iframe. (Note that I have to use an iframe instead of a DIV because of the content that will ultimately go there). I've tried both:

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click to see what you typed" />
  <br>
  <iframe id="compose" src={{> iframe-content}} height=600></iframe>
</template>

<template name="iframe-content">
  <body>
    <div contenteditable="true">
      Edit me
    </div> 
  </body>
</template>
```

This loads recursively, creating sub-Iframes continuously.

I've also tried

```
<iframe id="compose" src="content.html" height=600></iframe>
```

but Meteor munges the multiple HTML files together which also causes the iframe to fail.

The only thing that worked so far is SRCDOC instead of SRC, but that isn't well supported by multiple browsers like FF.

So, what's the trick to use an iframe within Meteor, preferably in the template rather than strictly through code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the 'public' folder.  Meteor leaves content in that folder alone, as described here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Move 'content.html' into a folder named 'public' at the root of your project/app and reference it like so in the html:

```
<head>
  <title>iframe</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />

  <iframe src="hello.html"></iframe>

</template>
```

To be clear for other readers, Meteor has no problem with iframes. The issue was with the location of the 'content.html' file the iframe referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your first code example:

```
<iframe id="compose" src={{> iframe-content}} height=600></iframe>
```

As far as I know, that's not how iframes work; you have to specify a url in the src attribute, you can't just put the actual HTML there. So that won't work.

As for the second example:

```
<iframe id="compose" src="content.html" height=600></iframe>
```

Where do you expect Meteor to get `content.html` if you haven't specified that that path exists? Since Meteor doesn't set up routing by default, there is no resource at /content.html. So you'd have to add the Meteor Router package or some similar routing mechanism, and then tell Meteor that when asked to serve /content.html, it should just return the content of some template. The challenging part is figuring out how to get Meteor to return "real" HTML and not the Meteor-wrapped live HTML construction that is usually served up.

Comment: I should have explicitly said that content.html was a file on disk that contains the necessary HTML, minus the tags that Meteor complains about like <HTML>. I was trying to avoid adding a routing package just for something simple like this. Adding a routing package also means I'll have to put more in code rather than declaratively.

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with iframe lately (mainly to encapsulate some page made for an app webviews) and if you put those html files in the `/public` folder and in the iframe src write absolute url `/file.html` then it just works.